# Store my App metrics in free Cloud database

Tags: java, android, android-database

I am designing an app. I want to know store some metrics about my app in free cloud database. The metrics includes which functionality users using more, number of downloads, user preferences etc. Later, I would like to query this database to understand app metrics.

I googled and found there are some free database hosting services like `FireBase, Buddy`. I am not sure which one to choose for my use case. Any suggestions?

I know this is not a programming question but its a `design requirement` I want to make, and if it not the correct place to ask, atleast route me to correct path instead of simply closing or down voting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer to my question finally! It is `Google Analytics`.

Simple and easier to configure and use.  Still exploring :-)